# ios using AFNetworking to upload a string to a server via a POST

Tags: ios, string, post, afnetworking

Until now, I was using `NSMutableURLRequest` but I was advised to change to `AFNetworking`, I have read through the `AFNetworking` doc, but I just don't understand how to use it.

I have a string in my iOS app that I want uploaded to the server via a POST method when the user touches the button UPLOAD.

I suppose this is what I need to use

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

but I don't get it. I only have a string I want to upload, I don't have any dictionary parameters. I also don't understand where to write down my servers' url. Do I simply replace http://example.com/resources.json ? My URL is finishing by .php  Does it matter ?

Could one of you please explain it to me silly-easy ?

Thanks for your time.

Update :

Actually I tried following the advice below but I got the following error message :

2014-02-10 16:06:54.662 AppName[5264:a0b] Error: Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html" UserInfo=0xc164d80 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=myURL.php, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: myURL.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Mon, 10 Feb 2014 16:06:54 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10, max=30";
    Server = Apache;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
} }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html}

I can't resolve the NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
The first one has to be string as it is what the php script on the server expects. The second one is answerField.text : What the user enters in the field before pushing on the upload button

Just don't understand what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JSON object (NSDictionary) which features a key (e.g "MyString") and a value, which will be your string. You can then send this across via AFNetorking. You do need to know the correct server address.

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"myURL": @"URL"};

Comment: Thank you for your answer CGRastermouse. I am not sure i understand. Why do you say the value will be my string (my URL) ?

Comment: Sorry updated my answer. You do need to know the upload URL for your service.

Comment: I know the upload URL, that's no problem. Why do I need to define the URL as a parameter ? How do I create a JSON Object? I started browsing about it, but they talk a lot about Java. Is the code I have shown above the right one to use ?

Comment: You can pass across the NSDictionary as your JSON object - it will work fine. You need to put your upload URL to replace @"http://example.com/resources.json" in the code above. Java has nothing to do with any of this.

Comment: OK, but I don't know the value of my String. It's the content of a field the user fills in.